# "bus speed", "rated bus speed", "stock bus speed"

Tags: motherboard, terminology, chipset, fsb

I was wondering what are differences between "bus speed", "rated bus speed", "stock bus speed"?

I saw in Speccy running on my laptop:

> Bus Speed 200.0 MHz
>   Rated Bus Speed   800.1 MHz
>   Stock Core Speed  1600 MHz
>   Stock Bus Speed   200 MHz

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Stock Bus Speed 200 MHz

Default Speed at which Front Side Bus aka FSB aka bus runs at.

> Bus Speed 200.0 MHz

Speed at which Front Side Bus aka FSB aka bus runs at.

> Rated Bus Speed 800.1 MHz

Effective speed of the bus ( recent Intel chipsets are quad pumped, hence 200MHzx4 = 800 MHz)

> Stock Core Speed 1600 MHz

Stock speed of your processor core.

( If you're wondering why "stock speed" v/s just "speed" - speed would refer to the overclocked speed ).